# Woocommerce For Contact Form 7 - How Can I Add Sku As A Form?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7, contact-form

[image]

As you can see the Sku information above, click "ASK ABOUT THIS PRODUCT" and there is no form label sku attached.

[image]

Can Help me? Thanks

Comment: This can be done adding a [hidden field to your contact form 7](https://contactform7.com/hidden-field/) for the Sku… Then you can add a hidden custom field with the sku to your products single pages and with some javascript you will be able to insert the product sku in Contact form hidden field… Then on your form "Mail" tab settings  you will be able to add that product sku to your mail message.

Comment: hi, I looked. I can not understand. what should i just write the sku code "label"?

can you please help @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Contact Form 7 (CF7) plugin
2. Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension plugin
3. Add a dynamic hidden (or not) field to your CF7 form like this:

   [dynamichidden SKU "CF7_get_custom_field key='_sku'"]